# Coldfusion UserAgent Logs?

Tags: coldfusion, user-agent

Are there any default ways to log what user agents hit your server? I need to compile a list of browsers that visit our website so we know what we best can support.

Thanks!

Comment: That's the sort of thing your web browser logs, and there are a goodly number of tools that will parse them for you. You can do something similar with CF, but you'd have to build it yourself and, of course, would only log visits to CF pages.

Comment: @Al you mean web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log `CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT`, maybe on Application.cfc's `onRequestStart()`?

or... use Google Analytics?

Comment: I would add it to onRequestEnd()

Answer (score 1):

Use the web server logs or an analytics tool like Google's. If you do not want to, or cannot use, Google use either of the following to help you:

1. [Microsoft Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) and [Log Parser Lizard](http://www.lizard-labs.net/log_parser_lizard.aspx) (one relies on the other). Parser is a command line tool that provides SQL syntax for parsing and reporting against IIS logs, and has the ability to work with several other formats as well. Lizard provides a GUI on top of it.
2. *nix command line grep, sed, sort: if you don't use *nix download [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to have these tools at your disposal anyway. This is the way I'll typically chomp on Apache logs and this will work for any sort of log you can imagine.

As far as doing it with ColdFusion @Henry provided a good answer.